# Prove that similar matrices have the same nullity.

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I approach this? I'm assuming it might have something to do with $B = P^{-1}AP$.

Comment: Say the null space of $A$ is $K$. Can you use $B = P^{-1}AP$ to write down an expression for the null space of $B$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices with $A=P^{-1}BP$.

The nullity of a matrix is the dimension of its nullspace. Thus we need only prove that 
$$
\dim\DeclareMathOperator{null}{null}\null A=\dim\null B
$$
To do so, let's define a linear map $f:\null A\to\null B$ by $f(\vec x)=P\vec x$. Note that $f$ is well-defined for $\vec x\in\null A$ implies 
$$
Bf(\vec x)=BP\vec x=PA\vec x=P\vec0=\vec 0
$$
Now, note that the map $g:\null B\to\null A$ defined by $g(\vec x)=P^{-1}\vec x$ is a linear inverse of $f$ (check this yourself!). It follows that $\null A$ and $\null B$ are isomorphic vector spaces. In particular, they have the same dimension.

If you're uncomfortable with the language of vector spaces and linear maps, you can take a more direct approach. Let $v_1,\dotsc,v_k$ be a basis for $\null A$. Can you prove that $P(v_1),\dotsc,P(v_k)$ is a basis for $\null B$? (Hints available upon request.)

Answer (score 5):

Similar matrices correspond to the *same* linear transformation, just seen with respect to different bases. The nullity of a matrix is the nullity of the corresponding linear transformation; it is the dimension of its null space, and so does not depend on the matrix representing the linear transformation.